# How to remove duplicates in a list of dictionaries containing lists?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has a list in itself:

```
    [{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The 
    Outsider']}, {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A 
    Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']},{'author': 'Stephen 
    King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}]
```

I have tried most ways for removing duplicates in a list of dictionaries, so far they seem not to work due to the array inside the dictionary.

The aim is to remove duplicates in the list of dictionaries in which each dictionary in itself has a list

The expected output in the above data should be:

```
    [{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The 
    Outsider']}, {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A 
    Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']}]
```

Comment: I edited in expected output. @Rakesh

Comment: Do you only care about exact duplicates (e.g. both the author name and the full list of books are identical)? Or do you want to do something different if the lists of books don't match, but the author names do?

Comment: @Blckknght i'm looking for exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dicts = [{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}, {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']},{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}]

def remove(dicts):
    for i in range(len(dicts)):
        if dicts[i] in dicts[i+1:]:
            dicts.remove(dicts[i])
            return remove(dicts)
        else:
            return dicts

print (remove(dicts))
```

output:

```
[{'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']}, {'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}]
```

Comment: Removing an element from a list when you know it's index is better done with `del dicts[i]` rather than indexing then searching with `remove`.

Comment: Hi, i have some new development, The function works great with len(list_data) < 800 however above that it pops out the error: **File "badger/football.py", line 16, in remove_dups
    return remove_dups(dicts)
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
  File "badger/football.py", line 14, in remove_dups
    if dicts[i] in dicts[i+1:]:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**

Comment: It's to avoid a stack overflow. The Python interpreter limits the depths of recursion to help you avoid infinite recursions, resulting in stack overflows. Try increasing the recursion limit (sys.setrecursionlimit) or re-writing your code without recursion.

sys.getrecursionlimit()

Return the current value of the recursion limit, the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python. It can be set by setrecursionlimit().

Comment: Perfect, super massive thanks @ncica ... found a great article on it too at [https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit]

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}, {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']},{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}]

checkVal = set()
result = []
for item in data:
    if item["author"] not in checkVal:   #Check if author & books in checkVal 
        result.append(item)              #Append result.
        checkVal.add(item["author"])     #Add author & books to checkVal 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']},
 {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway',
  'books': ['A Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']}]
```

---

Edit as per comment -- Check both `author` and `books`

```
checkVal = set()
result = []
for item in data:
    c = tuple(item["books"] + [item["author"]])
    if c not in checkVal:   #Check if author in checkVal 
        result.append(item)              #Append result.
        checkVal.add(c)     #Add author to checkVal 
pprint(result)
```

Comment: This only compares authors. If the same author has multiple dictionaries with different lists of books, it will produce the wrong result.

Comment: @Blckknght thats true, i accepted it since i can use that trail of thought and tweak it a little

Answer (score 0):

You should write some code that can transform a dictionary in your format into a hashable object. Then normal de-duplication code (using a `set`) will work:

```
data = [{'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']},
        {'author': 'Ernest Hemingway', 'books': ['A Moveable Feast', 'The sun Also Rises']},
        {'author': 'Stephen King', 'books': ['The stand', 'The Outsider']}]

seen = set()
result = []
for dct in data:
    t = (dct['author'], tuple(dct['books'])) # transform into something hashable
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        result.append(dct)
```

This code assumes your dictionaries only have the keys `'author'` and `'books'`, and nothing else. If you want to be a bit more generic and support other keys and values as well, you could extend the logic a bit. Here's an alternative computation of `t` that would support arbitrary keys (as long as they're all comparable) and any number of lists among the values:

```
t = tuple((k, tuple(v) if insinstance(v, list) else v) for k, v in sorted(dct.items())
```